# create more than one text file using matab's fopen in a for-loop

Tags: matlab, fopen

I'm quite new to Matlab and programming in general and would love to get some help with the following. I've look here on the website, but couldn't find an answer.

I am trying to use a for-loop and fprintf to give me a bunch of separate text files, whose file names contain the index I use for my for-loop. See for example this piece of code to get the idea of what I'd like to do:

```
for z=1:20
    for x=1:z;
        b=[x exp(x)];
        fid = fopen('table z.txt','a');
        fprintf(fid,'%6.2f, %6.2f\n',b);
        fclose(fid);
    end  
end
```

What I'm looking for, is a script that (in this case) gives me 20 separate .txt files with names 'table i.txt' (i is 1 through 20) where 
table 1.txt only contains [1, exp(1)],
table 2.txt contains [1, exp(1)] \newline [2, exp(2)]
and so on.

If I run the script above, I get only one text file (named 'table z.txt' with all the data appended underneath. So the naming of fopen doesn't 'feel' the z values, but interprets z as a letter (which, seeing the quotation marks doesn't really surprise me)

I think there must be an elegant way of doing this, but I haven't been able to find it. I hope someone can help.
Best,
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `num2str` and string concatenation `[ ... ]`.

```
fid = fopen( ['table ' num2str(z) '.txt'],'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening your file in the innermost loop is inefficient, you should create a file as soon as you know `z` (see example below). To format a string the same way that fprintf, you can use `sprintf`.

```
for z=1:20
    fname = sprintf('table %d.txt',z);
    fid = fopen(fname,'w');
    for x=1:z
        fprintf(fid,'%6.2f, %6.2f\n', x, exp(x));
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```